# Is it possible to see JVM opcodes from class file?

Tags: java

This is actually not about decompiling, I don't want to see the source, instead I want to see JVM instructions like `invoke some/package/method()V`.

Is there a tool for this purpose?

Comment: Try [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Eclipse + Bytecode Outline plugin for Eclipse http://andrei.gmxhome.de/bytecode/index.html. THis is how bytecode looks like

```
  public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V throws java/io/IOException 
   L0
    LINENUMBER 11 L0
    INVOKESTATIC test/Test.x ()V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 12 L1
    RETURN
...
```

Answer (score 5):

suppose you have a class file named MyClass.class

you can easily see what JVM instructions constitute your classfile by using a program shipped by jdk itself,in the same bin directory where java and javac exist.

```
 javap -c MyClass.class
```

The above command will provide you with what you be be looking for.

Comment: THIS is the best answer, as long as using internal JDK things is much more elegant, than anything else, since the question do not specify IDE involved.

Answer (score 2):

Try that: http://set.ee/jbe/

This tool allows you to see opcodes, attributes and edit it. It's really useful, but doesn't work with Java 8 lambdas.